# Any subtleties in source map line/column definitions when using source-maps for non-JS languages

Tags: unicode, line-breaks, utf-16, source-maps

I am getting a code generator to produce source maps that tracks line/column based on Unicode code-points with lines broken by (LF, CR, CRLF).  I worry about other line-breaks embedded in comments and supplementary characters might cause source-map consumers to disagree on which part of a source text a (line, column) pair references.

Specifically, I am confused by the [source-map v3](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1U1RGAehQwRypUTovF1KRlpiOFze0b-_2gc6fAH0KY0k/edit) specification's use of terms like

> the zero-based **starting line** in the original source

> the zero-based **starting column** of the line in the source represented

I imagine that these numbers are used by programmer tools to navigate to/highlight chunks of code in the original source.

### Problems due to different line break definitions

- [JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#prod-LineTerminatorSequence) recognizes CR, LF, CRLF, U+2028, U+2029 as line breaks
- [Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/whitespace.html) recognizes those and U+85 though or [only recognizes](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/comments.html) LF and CRLF as breaks depending on how you slice the grammar.
- [Java](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.4) only treats CR, LF, CRLF as line breaks.
- Languages that follow [Unicode TR #13](https://www.unicode.org/standard/reports/tr13/tr13-5.html#Interpreting%20characters%20in%20text) might additionally treat VT and FF as line breaks.

So if a source-map generator treats U+0085 (for example) as a newline and a source-map consumer does not, might they disagree about where a (source-line, source-column) pair points?

### Problems due to differing column definitions.

[Older versions of JavaScript](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf) defined a source text as UTF-16 code-units, suggesting that a column count is the number of UTF-16 code-units since the end of the last line-break.

> ECMAScript source text is represented as a sequence of characters in the Unicode character encoding, version 2.1 or later, **using the UTF-16 transformation format**.

But the current spec [does not describe source texts in terms of UTF-16](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#prod-SourceCharacter):

> *SourceCharacter*::
>     any Unicode code point

Are column counts likely to be thrown off if source-map consumers differently treat supplementary characters as occupying one code-point column or two UTF-16 columns?

For example, since '' is U+1d12C, a supplementary code-point encoded using two UTF-16 code-units, might column counts disagree for a line like

```
let  = "" /*  */ + ""
```

Is the `+` symbol at column 20 (zero-indexed by code-point) or column 23 (zero-indexed by UTF-16 code-unit)?

---

Am I missing something in the specification that clarifies this, or is there a de facto rule used by most source-map producers/consumers?

If these are problems, are there known workarounds or best practices when tracking line/column counts for source languages that translate to JS?

I will probably have to reverse-engineer what implementations like Mozilla's source-map.js or Chrome's dev console do, but thought I'd try and find a spec reference so I know whom to file bugs against and who is correct.